# How can I retrieve the AD account name for an email address using a sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow, active-directory

I am currently working on a list that will display contact information. I would like to set things up so that someone can just past several email addresses into a list (in the datasheet view), after which a workflow will go out and retrieve any relevant information from active directory.

I am able to retrieve data using the "User Profiles" data source, although I can only search for that data by using AD account names. I was able to make a column display AD account names by setting the field type to "Person or Group" and then setting "Show Field:" to "Account", although I am not able to copy the resulting value out of the cell (the copied value just ends up being the email address that I had originally copied into there, even though it display as an AD login name).

Is there a way that I can take an email address and then determine the owner's account name so that I can look up their info using their AD account name?

Comment: Where do You want to get User properties? It is SPD workflow or VS workflow? You know an e-mail and want to get username of owner of this email?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a SPD workflow, but you could do it with a Visual Studio one, essentially checking each record in AD against the email value. Kind of ugly.

Comment: @Omegacron hello, I was able to figure it out (had ended up asking the sharepoint engineering team at work). I set the Person or Group field/column to "work email", and then in the workflow I searched in the "User Profiles" data source using the Person or Group field as the search value (with the output of that field set to login ID). This allowed me to search for the AD data I needed without having to track down the AD account name first. Sorry if any of that is confusing. Glad that I got it working though

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Would you please share how you managed to to change the lookup field?

Comment: @Shadin sure, would be glad to. I have it saved on my work computer at the moment though so I won't be able to get it to you until tmw or sometime this weekend.